# Alternative ways to replace albeit

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What are the best words to replace albeit in this sentence?

"I say **albeit** regretfully"

Does "however" or "although" suits it well? Or are there better words?

Comment: Your sentence is not idiomatic or grammatical. Albeit means although, so you are basically saying 'I say although regretfully'

Comment: Is it grammatically wrong? I read so many court judgment from the uk using these words.

Comment: It is okay if you use the modifications that Dhanishtha Ghosh uses in their answer.

Comment: "many court judgments"  Can you then give us a single, complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I say albeit regretfully

This sentence is alright but needs some modifications as follows:

- I said, albeit regretfully. (*A complete stand-alone/independent sentence, indicating past action.*)
- I say, albeit regretfully [...] (*The brackets indicating that there should be predicate phrase after it, because present tense without it sounds weird, not incorrect though.*)

Without a predicate phrase in the above sentence, it would mean that you **always** regret what you say, since the present tense would then depict a habitual action.

Now, with moving to the alternative suggestion.

> *One must remember, **albeit** is a conjunction, and it does what conjunctions do—it connects clauses. **Albeit** can be used with concessive clauses and subordinate clauses. What you can’t do with ***albeit*** but can certainly do with ***although*** is introduce independent clauses. This is one of the reasons why the two words are not always interchangeable.* (From Grammarly)

For example:

> We decided to buy the car, albeit the price made us hesitate. (*Incorrect*)
>
> We decided to buy the car, although the price made us hesitate. (*Correct*)

In your case, you can use the alternatives interchangeably.

- I said, although regretfully, [...]
- I said, (even) though regretfully, [...] (*'even though' is used as a stronger way to say "though" or "although"*)
- I said, notwithstanding regretfully, [...] (*an unusual case*)
- I said, even if regretfully, [...]

This [blog article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/albeit/) might help you in future. 
This [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=although%20regretfully%2C%20even%20though%20regretfully%2C%20even%20if%20regretfully&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calthough%20regretfully%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceven%20though%20regretfully%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceven%20if%20regretfully%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Calthough%20regretfully%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceven%20though%20regretfully%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceven%20if%20regretfully%3B%2Cc0) might as well be remotely helpful to you.

Comment: I entirely appreciate your assistance. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Void You are right. I missed that one. Thanks! I didn't intend to disrespect the blogger in anyway. I will edit it.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh: If you don't like quotes in your answer (like me :P), you can just reword the copy-pasted part... or just say "According to Grammarly, bla bla bla". :)